# Несколько приложений в Yii2 зависящие от имени субдомена

Tags: php, yii

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное в Yii2:

```
www.domain.com / domain.com => Application #1

companyID*.domain.com => Application #2 (e.g. company1.domain.com, company2.domain.com...)

crm.domain.com => Application #3
```

Т.е. требуется создавать различные приложения в зависимости от имени субдомена в запросе. В данный момент, я прописал эту логику в `web/index.php`, которая создает и настраивает определенное приложение. Не совсем уверен, что это правильное решение, может быть лучше разбирать запрос сервером и направлять его в отдельные входные скрипты каждого из приложений.

В общем, как правильно настроить несколько приложений в Yii2, которые должны создаваться в зависимости от имени субдомена?

Вот небольшой реальный пример: https://schools.by/. Есть основной сайт `schools.by` со своим функционалом, и сайт школ `schoolID.schools.by` с другим функционалом.

Интересно, как называется подобная реализация в веб-разработка, где функции сайта зависят от имени субдоменов, чтобы было проще, что-нибудь в интернете откопать)

Answer (score 0):

[advanced шаблон приложения](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md) можешь просто посмотреть документацию где показан пример необходимый тебе ИМХО. А так, если в общем, можешь просто apache(nginx) к примеру настроить на определенные субдомены, чтобы он перенаправлял на необходимое тебе приложение (в доках подобный пример и рассмотрен, и да там не много читать)